# Xamarin IOS Tabbed Application Issue

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin

I'm currently using a tabbed application in iOS.

I'm using a `UITableView`. When I click/touch a row, it opens an another view and shows a back button on the left side of the `UINavigationBarItem`.

When i click/touch that one, it goes back to my previous View but my tabs are gone and that's not what i want.

If I do that in Android, I could make use of an ActivityGroup and set that in my TabHost.

Answer (score 0):

You could always override the PrepareForSegue in the view controller and set
segue.DestinationViewController.TabBarController = this.TabBarController

That a bit of a hack though. How are you opening the new view controller from the row? Have you set up a segue for that? If so the tab controller should stay

Comment: What is PrepareForSegue never heard of that im using for my cell event this    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)

Answer (score 0):

If your TabBar is disappearing it's usually because you are setting a different controller as the `UIWindow`s `RootViewController`.

Your application should have this structure:

`UIWindow` ->  `UITabBarController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `Tab1ViewController`

You have one `UINavigationController` for each tab in the `UITabBarController`.

If you are using Storyboard, using regular 'Push' segues should work as expected, and if you are doing this programmatically, you should simply push new controllers on top of the current view controller by:

```
var fooController = new UIViewController(); // Usually loaded from Xib
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(fooController, true);
```